# Why the test with "is" expression is more stable than the test with runtimeType?

Tags: dart

On dart tour page (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getting-an-objects-type) these have a statement that testing variable type with "is" expression is more stable. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `is` test is a *subtype* test.

If you do `e is Iterable`, you check whether the value of `e` implements `Iterable<dynamic>`, which includes any of `List`, `Set` and `Queue`, as well as all the subtypes of `Iterable` used internally by the runtime system, like `_TakeIterable` (which is used to implement `Iterable.take`).
It matches both values of type `Iterable<Object>` and `Iterable<int>`.
All of these are objects which can safely be used *as* an `Iterable`, and are intended to be used as such.

If you do `e.runtimeType == Iterable`, you are checking whether the `Type` object returned by `e.runtimeType` is equal to precisely the type `Iterable<dynamic>`. That will be false for any list, set or queue, for any actual iterable class which only implements `Iterable`, and even for something which returns the `Type` object of `Iterable<int>` or `Iterable<Object?>` from `runtimeType`.

I say that you check the object returned by `e.runtimeType`, not the run-time type of the value, because anyone can override the `runtimeType` getter.

I can make a class like:

```dart
class WFY {
  Type get runtimeType => Iterable<int>;
}
void main() {
  print(WFY().runtimeType == Iterable<int>);  // True!
}
```

The value returned by `runtimeType` *doesn't have to* have any relation to the actual runtime type of the object.
Obviously it usually has, because there is no benefit in overriding `runtimeType`, because you shouldn't be using it for anything anyway,

Even if your code works today, say:

```dart
assert(C().runtimeType == C); // Trivial, right!
```

it might fail tomorrow if I decide to make `C()` a factory constructor which returns a subtype, `_C` implementing `C`.
That's a change that is usually considered non-breaking, because the `_C` class can do everything the `C` interface requires, other than having `C` as actual runtime type.

So, doing `Type` object checks is not stable.

Another reason using `is` is better than comparing `Type` objects for equality is that it allows promotion.

```dart
num x = 1;
if (x is int) {
  print(x.toRadixString(16));  // toRadixString is on int, not on num
}
```

The `is` check is understod by the language, and trusted to actually guarantee that the value's runtime type implements the type you check against.

Comparing `Type` objects can mean anything, so the compiler can't use it for anything.

Some people like to use `runtimeType` in their implementation of `==`, like;

```
class MyClass {
  // ...
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    MyClass == other.runtimeType && other is MyClass && this.x == other.x;
}
```

This is intended to avoid subclass instance being equal to super-class instances when you ask the superclass, but not if you ask the subclass (the "`ColorPoint` problem", where `ColorPoint` extends `Point` with a color, and is equal to a another `ColorPoint` with the same coordinates and color, but if you ask a plain `Point` whether it's equal to a `ColorPoint`, it only checks the coordinates.)

This use of `runtimeType` "works", but is not without issues.
It means you cannot use mocks for testing.
It means you cannot create a subclass which *doesn't* extend the state, only the behavior, and which would want to be equal to the superclass instances with the same state.
And it means you do extra work, because you still need to cast the `other` object from `Object` to the surrounding type in order to access members, and `Type` object checks do not promote.

If possible, it's better to never allow subclasss of a concrete class that has a `==` method, and if you need to share other behavior, inherit that from a shared superclass.
(In other words: Don't extend classes that aren't intended to be extended, don't put `==` on classes which are intended to be extended.)